# Where can I find bulk miniatures of common folk?

Tags: miniatures

I am looking to teach a class on miniature painting in a fine arts camp that I run. I would like to supply 80-100 kids with their own miniature to paint. 
Keeping budget in mind, Is there a good place to purchase these?
I normally go to Reaper to find the ones for my personal gaming, but Im really looking for sets of common human minis.

Comment: you're welcome to come [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) about this though. We were just talking minis earlier in the day.